# What is the best way to track your mileage, routes and calories burned?

Tags: health, gps, smartphone-mount, performance-tracking

Recently I got a new cyclocross bike and now I am daily commuting around 25km (not much, but daily) and I am trying to calculate my diet, calories etc.

Now I am wondering if there is a good device or an android app that I could use precisely for:

- tracking routes
- mileages
- calories burned
- data connects with popular apps/platforms or can be exported (that is a huge plus)!

I have HTC One (m7), its a great phone and I would prefer to use it instead of buying some additional device.

I am asking here because there are literally TONS of this stuff online and it just becomes so hard to identify what is actually useful, while you guys might suggest something :)

Comment: To track calories burned with any more than the remotest level of accuracy you must have Heart rate monitoring. Plenty of Bluetooth HR monitors that will work   with Driod.

Comment: Do we/should we have a big list of tools?

Comment: I think that be great that we could have list of tools

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Moving it to another site doesn't make any sense. It's equally at home here.

Comment: I think we might have to start accepting bicycle-software questions, because they're starting to become common and like andy256 says, they're effectively on-topic. Wait until we start seeing mods for ebike firmware :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just started using an android app called *[IPbike](http://www.iforpowell.com/cms/index.php?page=ipbike)*.

- If you like tweaking settings and getting the items displayed *just right* it could be good for you; if not, look elsewhere.
- It can apparently sync with Strava etc, though I don't use that feature, and can import routes.
- It uses openstreetmap (a plus point for me as I've made a few contributions myself).
- It's designed to be a very configurable bike computer (I chuck the phone in my pannier).
- It costs but there's a free trial long enough to get used to it.
- It will track multiple bikes including in my case a bike called "running", though I haven't got it set up to do calories for running.
- It supports ANT+ and BTLE in case you buy sensors for it; I haven't tried this.

Comparisons:

- I didn't get on with the minimal info and huge map presented by the Strava android app.
- I used to use cardiotrainer (multi-activity) to do almost exactly what you ask for, but the route export feature (online) doesn't seem to be supported any more.

I don't have anything to do with the app author, but I'm told he's very helpful!

Comment: I will try it for sure!

Comment: The author looks at this forum occasionally though...  Any questions let me know.  Ifor

Comment: It syncs with Strava and a number of other sites. It supports ANT+ and BTLE sensors.

Answer (score 8):

There are several phone apps / web sites you can use. They all have a free mode and a premium mode. A few of them are:

- [Endomondo](https://www.endomondo.com/)
  Last time I used this (a couple of years back) it was able to give real time updates and "coaching" on your performance. It can handle many different sports and activities.
- [MapMyRide](http://www.mapmyride.com/)
  I haven't used this; some other people here do use it. Hopefully they'll say why.
- [Strava](https://www.strava.com/)
  I currently use this one. The main "benefit" is the social aspect, if you like to see what your friends are doing, and for them to see what you do.

I believe Endomondo and Strava do all that you say you want, and I expect that MapMyRide would do also. They all provide a data export feature.

Comment: Nice list, ill try Strava

Comment: MMR doesn't allow ride data to be exported from their own site. There certainly isn't an inbuilt feature at any rate. I believe there exists some sites that will do this as long as the ride data is public.

Comment: well I tried strava for more than a month and I am super disappointed: first of all auto-stop, horrible feature, works buggy, comes and goes whatever, had to turn it off. 2) Sometimes the app just thinks I am not moving then suddenly jumps half of track, thinking that I teleported there (my data, and gps work fines, also did testings for this route). 3) It provides way not enough data to be paid app: i would like to know the distance of uphill, downhill, my speed graph, other calculations... well anyway its only good if you want to show off with your friends via social part... poor!

Comment: Sorry to hear of your poor experience. I use the free version only. Auto-stop works for me. Very occasionally I see some GPS drift, but not enough to really effect the stats. It does show my total climb, but not descent total. It also shows my speed graph and power estimates. I see all this on my phone, and more is available on the desktop website. It's like you are using a different app! Have you tried the other apps, or IPbike that Chris H suggested?