# Are there any alternatives to Strava?

Tags: product-rec, software, strava

I have been using Strava for the last year to track my daily commutes, mountain bike rides and hikes.  Unfortunatly, I have found that Strava appears to be hiding my data from me.  It seems like I only have access to a small number of recent rides (maybe 10?) and I can't search for rides based on name.

I would like to switch to something that will not hide my data from me and will allow me to:

- Record rides & hikes
- View rides & hikes on a map afterwards
- Browse my rides/hikes
- Search the titles for specific things
- See things like yearly totals, maybe average speed
- Allow me to export my data to some open format (geoJson is preferred, but GPX works too)

Bonus points to any product that:

- Is free or has a one time cost
- Has clear info on how they are using your data
- Is opensource

Comment: So you want a product rec?

Comment: This is similar to http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31361/what-is-the-best-way-to-track-you-mileage-routes-and-calories-burned/. Since you've been around here longer than most of us, I'll leave it you to decide if it's actually a duplicate.

Comment: Regarding Strava, I think they've changed the way we find our data on the website. To get old data, we now have to go in via the Training Calender. I can see years back, to my first ride using Strava (using a free account).

Comment: You can export Strava rides to GPX. Open up a ride and click on the wrench on the left hand side of the screen. You should see an option to export GPX.

Comment: You can also export all rides as explained at https://support.strava.com/hc/en-us/articles/216918437-Exporting-your-Data-and-Bulk-Export

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: If anything, it could be a duplicate of the linked question. Moving it to another site doesn't make any sense. It's equally at home here.

Comment: I think that a strong case could be made that this question is a duplicate of the question liked by @andy256, however, I think this question is more general and *could* provide some broader answers.  However, if the community thinks that it is a dup, I am happy to close.

Answer (score 2):

We don't recommend products here, Mapmyride is what i and several friends use though, it's free. Does not allow exportation as far as i know.

That is a lot of wants out of an app. You might be better pressed to look into the high end gps enabled cycling computers rather than a phone based app.

Strava is one of the most popular for a reason, it offers more than most app type software. Assuming you don't, If you pay for the premium Strava i believe it unlocks a bit more usage data but i would read up on it before jumping in.

Often times apps ask for permissions for things that won't really effect your personal info, for example if it wants your FB friends list it will automatically link to your friends that have that app as well. Mapmyride gives me notifications that "Bob just rode 6.8 miles" etc.

Comment: Or a GPS enabled watch.

Answer (score 2):

If all your rides are already on **Strava**, you should have a look at [**veloviewer**](http://veloviewer.com/) which allows you to dig into it in ways Strava doesn't. You need to pay a small subcription (£10/year) to enjoy all of your rides, but if you do you have almost endless way to search through your activities as illustrated below.

[image]

The summary section on veloviewer is also endlessly configurable, showing you your progress as explained on the [veloviewer about page](http://blog.veloviewer.com/about/). Screenshot below borrowed from link.

[image]